# How do you play Stacked notes

Tags: notation

How do you play stacked notes,2 and 3 notes on top of each other on the staff for guitar[image: stacked notes]

Comment: BTW, the image in the question shows music written for piano.

Comment: That passage would not seem to be possible on a guitar.  At some points, you need 7 notes at once.  I have not checked but, at others, you made need to use difficult or impossible fingerings.  With some effort, it may be possible to rearrange it effectively for guitar.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you’re asking how to play chords on guitar. The way you do that is by fretting multiple strings at the frets corresponding to the notes of the chord. Then you pluck or strum all the strings that you have fretted. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Stacked notes mean you play all the notes at once -- a chord. On guitar the best approach would probably be to look at **what** chord you are supposed to play, as opposed to **which** specific notes that are in the voicing, as finding a way to play every note on different strings close enough to each other would take **even more** concentration than (single note) sheet reading already demands from a guitarist.